# What is wrong with this calculated field for total hours between two times in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, formula, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I am attempting to get the total hours between two times in a SharePoint 2007 list. Right now I have the formula as...

```
=INT(([Column2]-[Column1])*24)
```

...which I have looked up and says that it is the correct formula to do this. But, what I get is a weird date like "2/18/1900 12:00 AM" instead of what it should be: 26.

Another formula I tried was...

```
=TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"h")
```

...but, this will only get the difference in hours and not count the days (if they are more than one apart).

Both of the columns are Date & Time columns. So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take is that you set the output format of the calculated column to be Date and Time, while it should be of type number.

Comment: You are a genius, sir. That was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe I just made the same mistake myself some time ago ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In a calculated column, the number of hours between two times is:

```
=TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"h")
```

Providing that the difference is less than 24 hours. Otherwise, you'll need to look at getting the days difference and doing a multi-step calculation involving the number of days between the dates * 24 + the calc above.